# Sequence $\left(\frac{k^n}{2^k}\right)$ convergence through epsilon proof.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

> Prove that, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
>   $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{k^n}{2^k} = 0$$
>   using an $\epsilon-$proof.

As scratchwork, I've gotten to
$$\left|\frac{k^n}{2^k} - 0\right| = \frac{k^n}{2^k}\leq \epsilon$$

but I don't know how to get farther. I understand that if I can find a way to solve for k as a "function" of epsilon, then I can complete the proof. This is the part that I'm stuck on. We don't have many tools available yet, since we have only established the rational numbers and the concept of sequence convergence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k\gt 2n$. Using the binomial expansion of $(1+1)^k$ we find that 
$$(1+1)^k \gt \frac{(k)(k-1)(k-2)\cdots (k-n)}{(n+1)!}$$
($n+1$ terms).

Each of $k-1$, $k-2$, and so on up to $k-n$ is bigger than $k/2$. Thus
$$(1+1)^k \gt k \cdot \frac{k^n}{2^n(n+1)!}.$$
It follows that
$$\frac{k^n}{2^k}\lt \frac{2^n(n+1)!}{k}.$$
This inequality is strong enough to prove convergence to $0$.  If $K\gt 2n$ and $K\gt \frac{2^n(n+1)!}{\epsilon}$, and $k\gt K$, then the $k$-th term of your sequence is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: How does one arrive at the inequality $\sum_{\ell = 0}^k\binom{k}{\ell} > k(k-1)\cdots (k-n)$?  For example, take $n=2$ and $k=5>2n$.  Then, $2^k=32$ while $k(k-1)\cdots (k-n)=5\cdot 4\cdot 3=60$.   Something is not working.  ;-)) - Mark

Comment: Right, there is a missing term. Thank you, will fix.

Comment: Andre, you're welcome!  My pleasure.  - Mark

Comment: Yes, the $(n+1)!$ term was indeed missing.  This is a very quick way to find a suitable "$K(\epsilon)$".  I proceeded - brute force - and obtained a tighter "$K$" albeit, quite an ugly looking one.  ;-)) - Mark

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the logarithm function satisfies the inequality

$$\log(x)\le \frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha}$$

for $x>0$ and any $\alpha >0$.  Let us choose (arbitrarily) $\alpha =1/2$.  Then, we have

$$\log(x)\le 2\sqrt{x}$$

Note that the sequence of interest then satisfies the inequality

$$\begin{align}
\frac{k^n}{2^k}&=e^{n\log(k)-k\log(2)}\\\\
&\le e^{2n\sqrt{k}-k\log(2)}\\\\
&=e^{n^2/\log(2)}e^{-\log(2))(\sqrt k - n/\log(2))^2}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $k>\left(\frac{n}{\log(2)}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{n}{\log(2)}\right)^2-\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(2)}}\right)^2$.

And we are done!

Comment: What an awful $K$. +1.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD It sure is awful. ;-))  But it does work.  I'm sure one can find an easy simplification.  But brute force works well here.  And much appreciate the up vote!!  - Mark

Comment: I proved your inequality in my answer and carried things a little further.

Answer (score 2):

One can also reduce this problem to a simpler, already understood, base case. Since
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n>1+n·\frac1n=2
$$
we get
$$
\frac{k^n}{2^k}\le \left(\frac{k}{(1+\alpha)^k}\right)^n
$$
with $α=\frac1n$. For the inner sequence one gets for $k\ge 2$
$$
\frac{k}{(1+\alpha)^k}\le\frac{k}{\binom{k}{2}α^2}=\frac{2n^2}{k-1}
$$
Thus to get an upper bound of $\varepsilon>0$ for the original sequence one needs, in a very generous chain of bounds,
$$
k>1+\frac{2n^2}{\sqrt[n]ε}
$$

Comment: I like this one! +1 - Mark

Answer (score 1):

Taking logs,
we want to show that
$k \ln 2 - n\ln k
\to \infty$
as
$k \to \infty$.

Since $n$ is fixed,
this is the same as
$\frac{k}{\ln k}
\to 
\infty$.

There are many ways of showing this.
Here is an easy one
that uses only the definition of
$\ln$
and leads to the inequality
stated by Dr. MV.

If $a > 0$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(k)
&=\int_1^k \frac{dt}{t}\\
&\le\int_1^k \frac{dt}{t^{1-a}}\\
&=\int_1^k t^{a-1}dt\\
&=\frac{t^{a}}{a}|_1^k\\
&=\frac{k^{a}-1}{a}\\
&<\frac{k^{a}}{a}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\frac{k}{\ln k}
\gt \frac{k}{k^a/a}
=ak^{1-a}
$
for any $a > 0$.

If $a < 1$,
then this is unbounded.

The usual special case is
$a = 1/2$
which leads to
$\ln k < 2\sqrt{k}$
so
$\frac{k}{\ln k}
\gt \sqrt{k}/2
$.

Note that
by taking $a$ small,
this shows that
$\frac{\ln k}{k^a}
\to 0$
for any $a > 0$
as $k \to \infty$.

Here's the details,
which involve a
fairly standard trick.

We have
$\ln k
\lt \frac{k^{a/2}}{a/2}
= k^a\frac{2k^{-a/2}}{a}
$
so
$\frac{\ln k}{k^a}
\lt \frac{2}{ak^{a/2}}
\to 0$
as $k \to \infty$.